# How to get Android Local Service instance

Tags: android, service

I'm starting a service in my application using startService.

I do not want to use bindService as I want to handle the service life time myself.

How can I get an instance to the service started if I do not use bindService? I want to be able to get a handler I've created in the service class to post messages from the activity.

Thanks.

/ Henrik

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I do not want to use bindService as I
>   want to handle the service life time
>   myself.

That does not mean you have to avoid `bindService()`. Use both `startService()` and `bindService()`, if needed.

> How can I get an instance to the
>   service started if I do not use
>   bindService?

Either use `bindService()` with `startService()`, or use a singleton.

Comment: By "using a singleton" you mean that I should declare my methods static in the service class?

Comment: Worked as a charm with both bindService and startService. Thank you!

Comment: @Henrik: FWIW, by singleton, I meant that you'd have a static reference to your service, put there by the service's `onCreate()`, removed in the service's `onDestroy()`. That runs the risk of memory leaks, so binding is recommended wherever possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare if i do bindService() from my Activity, i get service instance perfectly but problem is when i go to device home screen from my application by clicking on device back button no action trigger from Notification expanded(Status Bar) bigView (RemoteView). I want to trigger play/pause, next froward button (My app is Music player app) action.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another approach:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private Binder binder;  

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        binder = new Binder();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public class Binder extends android.os.Binder {
        public MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

[onServiceConnected(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceConnected%28android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.IBinder%29) can cast its argument to `MyService.Binder` and call `getService()` on it.  This avoids the potential memory leak from having a static reference to the service.  Of course, you still have to make sure your activity isn't hanging onto a reference.