# FCM (FirebaseMessagingService) : how to register the app for push notifications not at installation

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a xamarin.forms app that needs to use push notifications. I realize that the app for android can be registered with FCM by calling OnNewToken() at installation time. But my app is assigned a group (subscription tag) only upon sign in, which of course happens after the installation. So at installation time the sign in information is not available. Could I get an advise on some work around? The same issue with iOS's RegisteredForRemoteNotifications()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the token at any time by calling `GetToken()`. Also see: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/blob/ccc5765399449d5b3d51052226545d95c499bc25/samples/com.google.firebase/firebase-messaging/FirebaseMessagingQuickstart/MainActivity.cs#L58

Comment: Thank you very much. I can get the token, but I don't see how I can register using this token. How can I access the current FirebaseService object?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025299/how-to-get-android-local-service-instance But you can also simply use the same code that you have in the service to save the token when you actively retrieve it with `getToken()`.

Comment: The code in the FirebaseService creates NotificationHub object, and into its contstructor among other things a Context of the FirebaseService is passed. Where would I take this context if I am not in the FirebaseService?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert on those things. It might be best to post a separate question for that, if a search doesn't find enough existing information.